# iPod touch and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipod-touch

How do you download JavaScript onto your iPod touch?

Comment: What's an itouch? What purpose do you have in downloading JavaScript onto such a thing?

Comment: @BoltClock the lazy way to say iPod Touch... my ears (eyes in this case) bleed every time I hear it...

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I know, I am reacting the exact same way as you are ;)

Answer (score 0):

Safai has built in support for JavaScript. Just point it at a webpage that uses the technology.